# UIRefreshControl is not hiding after refresh. iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am using `UIRefreshControl` in my table view. I have initiated refresh control in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
    [self.bestDealsTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

I have a target method for scrolling:

```
-(void) handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *) refreshControl{
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateDealsList) withObject:nil withObject:nil];
}
```

`updateDealsList` method:

```
- (void) updateDealsList {
    self.dealsService = [[BestDealsService alloc] initServiceWithDelegate:self isLocalCall:NO];
    [self.dealsService fetchBestDeals];
}
```

In my service response method:

```
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    self.isTableViewInRefreshMode = YES;
    [self.bestDealsTableView reloadData];
```

Now, I have two issues:
1. My refresh Control is not hiding on success response from my service. 
2. If I pull table view down, I can see a refresh control, but if I scroll down again, I see a new one below the previous one.

**Image for first refresh control:**

[image]

**Here, after scrolling down again:**

[image]
Note: I am using custom `TableViewCell`

Comment: can you try to put `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];` in `-(void) handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *) refreshControl{` before your call to `performSelector`. just to see if that fixes it.

Comment: No effect. Refresh control is still there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I fixed it:

```
// Pull To Refresh Code
if(self.refreshControl == nil){
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}
[self.myTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your `UIRefreshControl` with:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.bestDealsTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

and be sure to call `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];`

Answer (score -2):

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -100);
```